# preg_replace clips characters in string

Tags: php, preg-replace

i have a string (part of a JSON data) and want to parse it in brackets [...]. here is the example :

**For example** 
[-0.5937, 2.0734,-0.1577, 1.7941,0.2048, 1.5296] >>> **[-0.5937, 2.0734], [-0.1577, 1.7941], [0.2048, 1.5296]**

i wrote this PHP code works good but the problem is: when it finds the ',' and adding '], [' characters instead of it, deletes the some digits of coordinates. You can check it by adding **123456789** value after the coordinates. for example **-0.5937 => -0.5937123456789**  So how can i avoid deleting digits of coordinates ???

**Example Code**

```
<?php

$line = '[-0.5937, 2.0734,-0.1577, 1.7941,0.2048, 1.5296]';

$brackets = preg_replace('/\d,\S/', '], [', $line);
echo $brackets;

?>
```

Comment: is there always an even number of values?

Comment: i would be inclined to explode on the comma then loop

Comment: sometime negative coordinates could be possible so in this situaiton first letter is '-'   Example: -0.5937

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using an [assertion](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.assertions.php) to prevent the pattern from capturing the digit and the non-whitespace character. like so:

```
'/(?<=\d),(?<=\S)/'
```

Or, you can just change your pattern to:

```
'/,(?<=\S)/'
```

to ignore the digit character.

What I would recommend doing, however, would make your code not rely on the space before numbers. Use [preg_replace_callback](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php):

```
<?php

$line = '[-0.5937, 2.0734,-0.1577, 1.7941,0.2048, 1.5296]';
$i = 0;

function everyOther($matches) {
  $i++;
  if ($i % 2 == 1)
    return ',';
  else
    return '], [';
}

$brackets = preg_replace_callback(
                '/,/', 
                'everyOther',
                $line);

echo $brackets;

?>
```

This will replace every other comma.

Comment: This makes clearer but now it deletes some first digits and '-' negative char. Example coordinates: [-0.5937123456789, 2.0734123456789,-0.1577123456789, 1.7941123456789,1.2048123456789, 1.5296123456789]

Comment: @mete7 Fixed. I thought we were matching whitespace instead of non-whitespace. Had to double check.

Comment: Thanks Luke but i got an error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_FUNCTION

Comment: The anonymous function syntax was only added in PHP 5.3, it looks like. So, you may need to use a declared function. I'll post that syntax.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
$string = '[-0.5937, 2.0734,-0.1577, 1.7941,0.2048, 1.5296]';
$pattern = '~[[,]\s*(-?\d++(?>\.\d++)?)\s*,\s*(-?\d++(?>\.\d++)?)\s*(?:]|(?=(,)))~';

$result = preg_replace($pattern, '[$1, $2]$3 ', $string);
```

pattern details:

```
~                    # pattern delimiter
[[,]                 # a [ or a ,
\s*                  # optional spaces
(-?\d++(?>\.\d++)?)  # a number (group 1)
\s*,\s*              # ,
(-?\d++(?>\.\d++)?)  # (group 2)
\s*
(?:                  # non capturing group
    ]                # literal ]
  |                  # OR
    (?=(,))          # a lookahead that capture the comma (group 3)
)
~
```